# QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask not working when started from Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, multithreading

PyQGIS, using QGIS v 3.18. I am trying to run a processing algorithm in a separate thread in order to keep the UI responsive, using `QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask()`. I can run it successfully using `processing.run()`. If I use `QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask()` it fails - but only when implemented in a Plugin. When run in the Python console, it works.

Minimal example (based on [Cookbook example](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/tasks.html)) which does this:

1. Creates a point layer in memory, containing a single point.
2. Buffers it to a new memory layer and adds this to the project

I have tried four permutations, three of which work:

1. In Python console, with QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(): OK
2. In Python console, without QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(): OK
3. In a Plugin, with QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(): **Not OK**
4. In a Plugin, without QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(): OK

Whether `QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask()` is used or not is determined by `useTask`.

```
      def task_finished(context, successful, results):
      
        if not successful:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Task finished unsuccessfully','AlgRunnerTask',Qgis.Warning)
            return
        
        output_layer = context.getMapLayer(results['OUTPUT'])
        # because getMapLayer doesn't transfer ownership the layer will be
        # deleted when context goes out of scope and you'll get a crash.
        # takeResultLayer transfers ownership so it's then safe to add it to the
        # project and give the project ownership.
        if output_layer and output_layer.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer( context.takeResultLayer(output_layer.id()) )
            
      #
      
      def AlgRunnerTest(self):
      
        from functools import partial
      
        useTask = False
        algo_name = 'native:buffer'
    
        vl = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'test', 'memory')
        pnt = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(-75,40))
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setGeometry(pnt)
        vl.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
    
        params = {
            'INPUT':vl,
            'DISTANCE':1,
            'SEGMENTS':5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
            'JOIN_STYLE':0,
            'MITER_LIMIT':2,
            'DISSOLVE':True,
            'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
        
        if not useTask: # this works
    
            buffered_layer = processing.run(algo_name, params)['OUTPUT']
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffered_layer)
    
        else: # use QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask - does not work from Plugin
    
            alg = QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithmById( algo_name )
            context = QgsProcessingContext()
            feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
            
            task = QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(alg, params, context, feedback)
            task.executed.connect(partial(self.task_finished, context))
            QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask( task )
            
        #
      #
```

The result in case 3 above (implemented in Plugin, `useTask=True`) is that it crashes. Before this happens, I get the error message `Could not load source layer: Invalid value`.

I suspect this could be to do with scope as per [issue #38583](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38583) on GitHub(?) If it is, I am not sure how to get around it. I have tried making `context` and `feedback` into class variables without resolving the problem.